# Import Excel xlsx file to gsheet allways into same target file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, import-from-excel

I want to import a file called ExcelToImport.xlsx file allways into a same file called UpdatedGSheet.gsheet file

I have created the UpdatedGSheet.gsheet file and taken its id from its url
I have created a gsheet file called Import Excel Scrip where I add the follow script (i have taken this code from other post)

```
function myFunction() {
  const xlsxFileName = "ExcelToImport.xlsx";  // Please set the filename of XLSX file.
  const spreadsheetId = "1IrfZpQhXvlyK5HNSwgKgXYyOB_____Dj1DrRsJlPVpE";  // Please set the Spreadsheet ID. This Spreadsheet is overwritten by EXCEL data.-(the id has been modified little)
  const xlsx = DriveApp.getFilesByName(xlsxFileName);
  if (!xlsx.hasNext()) throw new Error("No excel file.");
  Drive.Files.update({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, spreadsheetId, xlsx.next().getBlob());
}
```

but after run I take this error message

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.files.update failed with error: File not found: 1IrfZpQhXvlyK5HNSwgKgXYyOB_____Dj1DrRsJlPVp
```

I have added the Api Service in Services Section of my sheet

I can not find where is the problem.

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue

The `Drive.Files`, need the parameter "supportsAllDrives:true" (i don't know why :D)

```
Drive.Files.update(
  {
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
  },
  spreadsheetId,
  xlsx.next().getBlob(),
  {
    supportsAllDrives: true
  }
);
```

It works fine now.

Regards !!!